# Problem to get value from a range dynamically and set this value to other range of another sheet

Tags: vba, sourceforge-appscript

Actually i have two sheet one is master sheet and other is data sheet. i want to input data in every 5th row and starting with 4th row(i.e 4, 9, 14, ...etc) in the Master sheet("1EzemDPlSwWo5SJsJkePbPUlrOh-BoCa9svu9i85uZfQ"). Now i want these data to Data sheet("1hdbT-g2gDdLVng6jMieOULgjWlPlRckl8sUS_UGJroQ") in every 5th row starting with 7th row.

```
function myFunction() {
var An = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1EzemDPlSwWo5SJsJkePbPUlrOh-BoCa9svu9i85uZfQ");
 var GetSa1 =An.getSheetByName("CLASS I  FORMATIVE(A.N)");
var Fs = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1hdbT-g2gDdLVng6jMieOULgjWlPlRckl8sUS_UGJroQ");
 var GetFh1 =Fs.getSheetByName("REPORT CARD FOR ALL CLASS 2023");
 
 var Ps1 =[];
for(var i = 4;i<=44;i=i+5){
  Ps1=(GetSa1.getRange("O"+[i]).getValue());
Logger.log( Ps1);
for(var j=7;j<=44;j=j+5){ 
 GetFh1.getRange("R"+[j]).setValue(Ps1);

      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider adding more details about how you want the application to work, the test inputs used and applicable diagnostic information.

Comment: Thank you JohnH for replying me. Actually i have two sheet one is master sheet and other is data sheet. i want to input data in every 5th row and starting with 4th row(i.e 4, 9, 14, ...etc) in the Master sheet("1EzemDPlSwWo5SJsJkePbPUlrOh-BoCa9svu9i85uZfQ"). Now i want these data to Data sheet("1hdbT-g2gDdLVng6jMieOULgjWlPlRckl8sUS_UGJroQ") in every 5th row starting with 7th row.

Comment: var Ps1 =[];
for(var i = 4;i<=44;i=i+5){
  Ps1=(GetSa1.getRange("O"+[i]).getValue());
   GetFh1.getRange("R"+[i+3]).setValue(Ps1);
Logger.log( Ps1);

Comment: Your comment addition may help. In general, it is usually better to edit your question to add additional content.